# Complete a string column according to a condition on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'V1':[1,2,np.nan,4,np.nan], 'V2':[-9,8,-7,0,np.nan], 'Label':['a','b','c','d','e']})
    V1   V2 Label
0  1.0 -9.0     a
1  2.0  8.0     b
2  NaN -7.0     c
3  4.0  0.0     d
4  NaN  NaN     e
```

I would like to add '_same_sign' to the value of 'Label' column if the values in 'V1' and 'V2' have strictly the same sign. I guess I have to use an apply, I tried the following but it didn't work (I'm not very familiar with apply, sorry if that hurts you) :

```
df['Label'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['Label'] + '_same_sign' if x['V1']*x['V2']>0 else x['Label'])
```

Could you please help me to have the correct code ?

**Expected output :**

```
    V1   V2        Label
0  1.0 -9.0            a
1  2.0  8.0  b_same_sign
2  NaN -7.0            c
3  4.0  0.0            d
4  NaN  NaN            e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loopy solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `axis=1`:

```
df['Label'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['Label'] + '_same_sign' if x['V1']*x['V2']>0 else x['Label'], axis=1)
```

Non loop solution with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = df['V1']*df['V2']>0

df['Label'] = df['Label'].mask(m ,df['Label'] + '_same_sign')
```

Or with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df['V1']*df['V2']>0

df.loc[m, 'Label'] +=  '_same_sign'
#working same like
#df.loc[m, 'Label'] =  df.loc[m, 'Label'] + '_same_sign'
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Would you suggest a method rather than another ?

Comment: @Ewdlam - My opinion is last one.